# How to load a page in Javascript and MD5 hash it to make sure it is the page we are looking for

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a page in Javascript (basically request google.com, load the google.com source code) and then MD5 Hash that (or SHA-1, doesn't make much of a difference) and then compare that to the value I already have to confirm that this is google.com (as an example).

To clarify, here is a better example:

I have an app with the url (myurl.com).

The source code looks like this: `<head></head><body></body>`

I want to be able to load that source code using Javascript, hash that content into a value, compare that value with a pre-calculated hash value of the same content and then if and only if they are equal show a result. Otherwise, I know that I am not loading the exact same content on this page and will show some sort of an error.

Please do let me know if this is not clear enough or if any more info is needed.

Comment: Why don't you use SSL?

Comment: @KeesdeWit, I am looking for this implementation but if you have other suggestions please feel free to mention them, I would love to hear more.

Comment: please post your code and a more concrete question about it, and we will then help. If you just don't know where to begin, try find tutorials on node.js `http.request` or cscript `WinHttpRequest` or  `jQuery.ajax()`....

Comment: If you request the content through https/ssl there is no need to confirm that google.com is in fact google.com because you can trust upon it's SSL certificate that proofs the origin of your content. Use the ajax cross domain function as below and skip the md5 hash (which is also a poor algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery to download the page and [cross-domain-ajax](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax) for the cross domain request.

```
function utf8_encode ( string ) {

    string = (string+'').replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").replace(/\r/g, "\n");

    var utftext = "";
    var start, end;
    var stringl = 0;

    start = end = 0;
    stringl = string.length;
    for (var n = 0; n < stringl; n++) {
        var c1 = string.charCodeAt(n);
        var enc = null;

        if (c1 < 128) {
            end++;
        } else if((c1 > 127) && (c1 < 2048)) {
            enc = String.fromCharCode((c1 >> 6) | 192) + String.fromCharCode((c1 & 63) | 128);
        } else {
            enc = String.fromCharCode((c1 >> 12) | 224) + String.fromCharCode(((c1 >> 6) & 63) | 128) + String.fromCharCode((c1 & 63) | 128);
        }
        if (enc != null) {
            if (end > start) {
                utftext += string.substring(start, end);
            }
            utftext += enc;
            start = end = n+1;
        }
    }

    if (end > start) {
        utftext += string.substring(start, string.length);
    }

    return utftext;
}

function md5 (str) {
  // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
  // +   original by: Webtoolkit.info (http://www.webtoolkit.info/)
  // + namespaced by: Michael White (http://getsprink.com)
  // +    tweaked by: Jack
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // -    depends on: utf8_encode
  // *     example 1: md5('Kevin van Zonneveld');
  // *     returns 1: '6e658d4bfcb59cc13f96c14450ac40b9'
  var xl;

  var rotateLeft = function (lValue, iShiftBits) {
    return (lValue << iShiftBits) | (lValue >>> (32 - iShiftBits));
  };

  var addUnsigned = function (lX, lY) {
    var lX4, lY4, lX8, lY8, lResult;
    lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
    lY8 = (lY & 0x80000000);
    lX4 = (lX & 0x40000000);
    lY4 = (lY & 0x40000000);
    lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF) + (lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
    if (lX4 & lY4) {
      return (lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
    }
    if (lX4 | lY4) {
      if (lResult & 0x40000000) {
        return (lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
      } else {
        return (lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
      }
    } else {
      return (lResult ^ lX8 ^ lY8);
    }
  };

  var _F = function (x, y, z) {
    return (x & y) | ((~x) & z);
  };
  var _G = function (x, y, z) {
    return (x & z) | (y & (~z));
  };
  var _H = function (x, y, z) {
    return (x ^ y ^ z);
  };
  var _I = function (x, y, z) {
    return (y ^ (x | (~z)));
  };

  var _FF = function (a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) {
    a = addUnsigned(a, addUnsigned(addUnsigned(_F(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return addUnsigned(rotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  var _GG = function (a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) {
    a = addUnsigned(a, addUnsigned(addUnsigned(_G(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return addUnsigned(rotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  var _HH = function (a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) {
    a = addUnsigned(a, addUnsigned(addUnsigned(_H(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return addUnsigned(rotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  var _II = function (a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) {
    a = addUnsigned(a, addUnsigned(addUnsigned(_I(b, c, d), x), ac));
    return addUnsigned(rotateLeft(a, s), b);
  };

  var convertToWordArray = function (str) {
    var lWordCount;
    var lMessageLength = str.length;
    var lNumberOfWords_temp1 = lMessageLength + 8;
    var lNumberOfWords_temp2 = (lNumberOfWords_temp1 - (lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64)) / 64;
    var lNumberOfWords = (lNumberOfWords_temp2 + 1) * 16;
    var lWordArray = new Array(lNumberOfWords - 1);
    var lBytePosition = 0;
    var lByteCount = 0;
    while (lByteCount < lMessageLength) {
      lWordCount = (lByteCount - (lByteCount % 4)) / 4;
      lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4) * 8;
      lWordArray[lWordCount] = (lWordArray[lWordCount] | (str.charCodeAt(lByteCount) << lBytePosition));
      lByteCount++;
    }
    lWordCount = (lByteCount - (lByteCount % 4)) / 4;
    lBytePosition = (lByteCount % 4) * 8;
    lWordArray[lWordCount] = lWordArray[lWordCount] | (0x80 << lBytePosition);
    lWordArray[lNumberOfWords - 2] = lMessageLength << 3;
    lWordArray[lNumberOfWords - 1] = lMessageLength >>> 29;
    return lWordArray;
  };

  var wordToHex = function (lValue) {
    var wordToHexValue = "",
      wordToHexValue_temp = "",
      lByte, lCount;
    for (lCount = 0; lCount <= 3; lCount++) {
      lByte = (lValue >>> (lCount * 8)) & 255;
      wordToHexValue_temp = "0" + lByte.toString(16);
      wordToHexValue = wordToHexValue + wordToHexValue_temp.substr(wordToHexValue_temp.length - 2, 2);
    }
    return wordToHexValue;
  };

  var x = [],
    k, AA, BB, CC, DD, a, b, c, d, S11 = 7,
    S12 = 12,
    S13 = 17,
    S14 = 22,
    S21 = 5,
    S22 = 9,
    S23 = 14,
    S24 = 20,
    S31 = 4,
    S32 = 11,
    S33 = 16,
    S34 = 23,
    S41 = 6,
    S42 = 10,
    S43 = 15,
    S44 = 21;

  str = utf8_encode(str);
  x = convertToWordArray(str);
  a = 0x67452301;
  b = 0xEFCDAB89;
  c = 0x98BADCFE;
  d = 0x10325476;

  xl = x.length;
  for (k = 0; k < xl; k += 16) {
    AA = a;
    BB = b;
    CC = c;
    DD = d;
    a = _FF(a, b, c, d, x[k + 0], S11, 0xD76AA478);
    d = _FF(d, a, b, c, x[k + 1], S12, 0xE8C7B756);
    c = _FF(c, d, a, b, x[k + 2], S13, 0x242070DB);
    b = _FF(b, c, d, a, x[k + 3], S14, 0xC1BDCEEE);
    a = _FF(a, b, c, d, x[k + 4], S11, 0xF57C0FAF);
    d = _FF(d, a, b, c, x[k + 5], S12, 0x4787C62A);
    c = _FF(c, d, a, b, x[k + 6], S13, 0xA8304613);
    b = _FF(b, c, d, a, x[k + 7], S14, 0xFD469501);
    a = _FF(a, b, c, d, x[k + 8], S11, 0x698098D8);
    d = _FF(d, a, b, c, x[k + 9], S12, 0x8B44F7AF);
    c = _FF(c, d, a, b, x[k + 10], S13, 0xFFFF5BB1);
    b = _FF(b, c, d, a, x[k + 11], S14, 0x895CD7BE);
    a = _FF(a, b, c, d, x[k + 12], S11, 0x6B901122);
    d = _FF(d, a, b, c, x[k + 13], S12, 0xFD987193);
    c = _FF(c, d, a, b, x[k + 14], S13, 0xA679438E);
    b = _FF(b, c, d, a, x[k + 15], S14, 0x49B40821);
    a = _GG(a, b, c, d, x[k + 1], S21, 0xF61E2562);
    d = _GG(d, a, b, c, x[k + 6], S22, 0xC040B340);
    c = _GG(c, d, a, b, x[k + 11], S23, 0x265E5A51);
    b = _GG(b, c, d, a, x[k + 0], S24, 0xE9B6C7AA);
    a = _GG(a, b, c, d, x[k + 5], S21, 0xD62F105D);
    d = _GG(d, a, b, c, x[k + 10], S22, 0x2441453);
    c = _GG(c, d, a, b, x[k + 15], S23, 0xD8A1E681);
    b = _GG(b, c, d, a, x[k + 4], S24, 0xE7D3FBC8);
    a = _GG(a, b, c, d, x[k + 9], S21, 0x21E1CDE6);
    d = _GG(d, a, b, c, x[k + 14], S22, 0xC33707D6);
    c = _GG(c, d, a, b, x[k + 3], S23, 0xF4D50D87);
    b = _GG(b, c, d, a, x[k + 8], S24, 0x455A14ED);
    a = _GG(a, b, c, d, x[k + 13], S21, 0xA9E3E905);
    d = _GG(d, a, b, c, x[k + 2], S22, 0xFCEFA3F8);
    c = _GG(c, d, a, b, x[k + 7], S23, 0x676F02D9);
    b = _GG(b, c, d, a, x[k + 12], S24, 0x8D2A4C8A);
    a = _HH(a, b, c, d, x[k + 5], S31, 0xFFFA3942);
    d = _HH(d, a, b, c, x[k + 8], S32, 0x8771F681);
    c = _HH(c, d, a, b, x[k + 11], S33, 0x6D9D6122);
    b = _HH(b, c, d, a, x[k + 14], S34, 0xFDE5380C);
    a = _HH(a, b, c, d, x[k + 1], S31, 0xA4BEEA44);
    d = _HH(d, a, b, c, x[k + 4], S32, 0x4BDECFA9);
    c = _HH(c, d, a, b, x[k + 7], S33, 0xF6BB4B60);
    b = _HH(b, c, d, a, x[k + 10], S34, 0xBEBFBC70);
    a = _HH(a, b, c, d, x[k + 13], S31, 0x289B7EC6);
    d = _HH(d, a, b, c, x[k + 0], S32, 0xEAA127FA);
    c = _HH(c, d, a, b, x[k + 3], S33, 0xD4EF3085);
    b = _HH(b, c, d, a, x[k + 6], S34, 0x4881D05);
    a = _HH(a, b, c, d, x[k + 9], S31, 0xD9D4D039);
    d = _HH(d, a, b, c, x[k + 12], S32, 0xE6DB99E5);
    c = _HH(c, d, a, b, x[k + 15], S33, 0x1FA27CF8);
    b = _HH(b, c, d, a, x[k + 2], S34, 0xC4AC5665);
    a = _II(a, b, c, d, x[k + 0], S41, 0xF4292244);
    d = _II(d, a, b, c, x[k + 7], S42, 0x432AFF97);
    c = _II(c, d, a, b, x[k + 14], S43, 0xAB9423A7);
    b = _II(b, c, d, a, x[k + 5], S44, 0xFC93A039);
    a = _II(a, b, c, d, x[k + 12], S41, 0x655B59C3);
    d = _II(d, a, b, c, x[k + 3], S42, 0x8F0CCC92);
    c = _II(c, d, a, b, x[k + 10], S43, 0xFFEFF47D);
    b = _II(b, c, d, a, x[k + 1], S44, 0x85845DD1);
    a = _II(a, b, c, d, x[k + 8], S41, 0x6FA87E4F);
    d = _II(d, a, b, c, x[k + 15], S42, 0xFE2CE6E0);
    c = _II(c, d, a, b, x[k + 6], S43, 0xA3014314);
    b = _II(b, c, d, a, x[k + 13], S44, 0x4E0811A1);
    a = _II(a, b, c, d, x[k + 4], S41, 0xF7537E82);
    d = _II(d, a, b, c, x[k + 11], S42, 0xBD3AF235);
    c = _II(c, d, a, b, x[k + 2], S43, 0x2AD7D2BB);
    b = _II(b, c, d, a, x[k + 9], S44, 0xEB86D391);
    a = addUnsigned(a, AA);
    b = addUnsigned(b, BB);
    c = addUnsigned(c, CC);
    d = addUnsigned(d, DD);
  }

  var temp = wordToHex(a) + wordToHex(b) + wordToHex(c) + wordToHex(d);

  return temp.toLowerCase();
}


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get("http://www.google.com/", function(page)
    {
        if(md5(page) == "1441a7909c087dbbe7ce59881b9df8b9")
            console.log("matches");
        else
            console.log("Does not match");
    });
});
```

Comment: This is cool, thanks for providing this. However, this is not working when giving a port to the url (for example: https://google.com:8080) or something similar just simply returns nothing. Is there a reason for that?